# Removing draggable properties

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a set of images that have `draggable=true` setting.  These images are intended to be dragged then dropped onto a google map view and create a marker at the drop location.  To prevent duplicate images on the map, I'd like to disable the draggable setting and alter the opacity.

My map droppable and photo draggable handlers are

```js
$("#photo"+i).draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move",
  containment:  'body',
  start: function(e){
    $(this).addClass("fade");
    currentPhoto = $(this);   
  }
});

$("#map").droppable({
  drop: function(e){
    var point = new google.maps.Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var data = {
      "location": overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(point),
      "photo": currentPhoto
    }

    makeMarkers(data.location, $(data.photo).attr("src"), $(data.photo).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Inside `makeMarkers`, the `type` value is used to determine if the markers are being created on page load from database retrieval values or as the ID of the photo image being dragged.

```js
function makeMarkers(location, title, type){
   //variable and marker initialization here    

  if (type == "onload")
    newMarker.setIcon(savedLocation);
  else {
    newMarker.setIcon(unsavedLocation);
    $("img."+type).attr("draggable", "false");
    $("img."+type).attr("opacity", "0.5");
    console.log("Disabling draggability of " +type);
  }

   //marker event handlers here
}
```

I can drag and drop the image and a new marker is created at the location.  However, the image properties are unchanged.  How can I enable the ability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) instead of `.attr()`.

This code should do the trick:

```
function makeMarkers(location, title, type){
   //variable and marker initialization here    

  if (type == "onload")
    newMarker.setIcon(savedLocation);
  else {
    newMarker.setIcon(unsavedLocation);
    $("img."+type).removeAttr("draggable");
    $("img."+type).attr("opacity", "0.5");
    console.log("Disabling draggability of " +type);
  }

   //marker event handlers here
}
```